# How can I control a function on a raspberry pi based on a button selection on a website that I create?

Tags: raspberry-pi, web, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi3

I'm doing a DIY project that requires me to activate motors based on selections made on a custom website I'm creating on localhost. I'm really new to raspberry pi's and I really have no idea of how to connect input on a website and make it do something in the real world. My website is almost done and I'm thinking about whether it would be a better idea to create a pop up or to link it to a completely new website. If it is possible to make the raspberry pi recognize a link and notice the browser accessing the link, then I rather make a new html page for the function. If there is another way to do so like by adding a photo from the local folder and then making the pi look for the file being accessed locally. Although I have these ideas about how to do it, im really lost on how to go about it in the coding realm, im new to coding and python in general. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can do this is by using PHP to write to a txt file or database. 
Then using a python code to capture the echo-ed value of in the text file or database and then manipulating the GPIOs based on this value. 
If you have a single or only few motors to be manipulated then the text file way should do fine. You must also note that although this is very simple to implement, and you'll find all the necessary code online, it is far from secure. 
Using a database is better if you have more no. of entities to control. It'll also be a bit more secure.